# how to use subquery as variable and use the variable in return query - Postgres function

Tags: xml, postgresql, function

I have data as xml file so the first step is to convert that into columns, later use these columns in my select query.

both the steps should be inside the same function ( convert XML to columns, SQL query).

```
name_a := (select name from(SELECT unnest (xpath(' //name/text()',
                   xml_string))::text as name)as foo))
```

`return query select * from table1 inner join table2 on table2.name in (name_a)`

Answer (score 0):

It would be best not to use a variable, but put the subquery directly into the `IN` clause in the final statement.

If you want to use a variable, it should be an array variable. Either don't `unnest` use use `array_agg` to convert it back into an array.

That array valiable can then be used like this:

```
... WHERE table2.name = ANY (array_var)
```